# Is the Jelastic GC agent automatically enabled for newly created "Java Engine" environments?

Tags: jelastic

The [docs](https://docs.jelastic.com/garbage-collector-agent) say that it's automatically enabled for newly created Java Application servers (e.g. Tomcat, Jetty) but is it also enabled for the Java Engine environment? I looked through the folder structure of my Java Engine environment but I couldn't see `jelastic-gc-agent.jar` anywhere.

If it isn't automatically enabled for the Java Engine environment, then how do I manually enable it?

Comment: Which version of Java Engine do you run? The agent should be enabled by default for all java engines with JDK version < 12. You can check if the agent is attached via `ps -ax | grep java`

Comment: By default, GC is saved in the "java_agent" directory in the root of the container. 
When you create a new container, it starts automatically with GC.

Comment: Thanks yes I can see the gc agent is active with `ps -ax | grep java` and also I can see the file `/java_agent/jelastic-gc-agent.jar`